# Get 2 variable from $.post() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I want to get 2 var from a form with live result with $.post() function in javascript, but when i add second var in js code my php page doesn't load anymore.

this is my script:

```
function getStates(value) {
  $.post("live.php", { name:value, price_var:price_value }, function(data) {
    $("#total").show();
    $("#total").html(data);
  });
}
```

this is my input:

```
<input name="username" onkeyup="getStates(this.value)"/>
<input name="username" onkeyup="getStates(this.price_value)"/>
```

and this is my php page ( so simple ) :

```
<?php echo $_POST["name"]. ' ' .$_POST["price_var"]; ?>
```

this works correctly, but i want get another var

Comment: Could you show us the code you've used to pass two variables in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never get the two variables into your js script.

Add id to your inputs

```
 <input id='bar' name="username" onkeyup="getStates()"/>
 <input id='foo' name="price_value" onkeyup="getStates()"/>
```

Change your js code to get the values

```
function getStates() {
  // Get value here
  var name = $('#bar').val();
  var price_value = $('#foo').val();
  // end get value
  $.post("live.php", { name:name, price_var:price_value }, function(data) {
      $("#total").show();
      $("#total").html(data);
  });
}
```

Your php code looks ok